# Good practice with Mockito And BufferedReader

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, mockito

I'm trying to test a class that makes File/Stream treatment. For instance, the method `readFile` will use `BufferedReader` to return an `ArrayList` of String with every lines of the file inside:

```
public ArrayList<String> readFile(String fileName)
{
    ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
    FileReader fr = null;
    BufferedReader br = null;
    try {

        fr = new FileReader(STORAGE_DIRECTORY+fileName);
        br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        String sCurrentLine;

        while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            result.add(sCurrentLine);
        }
    }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {


            return new ArrayList<String>();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            return new ArrayList<String>();
        }

        br.close();
        fr.close();


        return result;
    }
```

But when I use Mockito in order to mock `bufferedReader` method "readLine()",a `FileNotFoundException` is thrown because of `FileReader` constructor. Must I use `temporaryFile` or Mock `FileReader` constructor ?

```
@Test
public void readFileTest5() throws Exception {
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = Mockito.mock(BufferedReader.class);
    FileReader fileReader = Mockito.mock(FileReader.class);
    when(BufferedReader.readLine()).thenReturn("abc");
    assertEquals("",new ArrayList<String>(), FileUtil.readFile("abc"));
}
```

Thank you

Comment: My bad, i should have write the top of the class. BufferedReader is here an instance of the classe injected with annotation (spring style).
`@MockBean
 private BufferedReader bufferedReader;
 
 @MockBean
 private java.io.FileReader fileReader;
 
 @MockBean
 private File File;

  @InjectMocks
    private com.example.system.FileUtil FileUtil;`

Comment: You should extract buffer construction into separate method and mock that method to return mocked BufferedReader whose "readLine" returns what you want. Or possibly don't try to mock this simple stuff: you have much more apparent problem with resource leaks.

Comment: Ok thank you, what do you mean with 'ressource leaks' ?

Comment: You don't close your readers when exception occurs.

Comment: Thank you, I just removed some part of the code to focus on my problem but I manage this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your FileUtil does read a file referenced by name, you do need to create a file in the file system. This is easily done by

```
File tempFile = File.createTempFile("temp", ".tmp");
tempFile.deleteOnExit(true);
```

some words on your implementation code:

```
ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
// combine directory and file name like this
File f = new File(STORAGE_DIRECTORY, fileName);
// use try-with-resource here, like this:
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f)))  {

    String sCurrentLine;

    while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
        result.add(sCurrentLine);
    }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // no need to create a new list
        return Collections.emptyList()
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return Collections.emptyList()
    }

    // you don't need to close the reader if you use try-with-resource

    return result;
}
```

You can of course just use Files#readAllLines.

```
try {
    return Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(STORAGE_DIRECTORY, fileName), StandardCharsets.UTF-8);
} catch (IOException e) {
    return Collections.emptyList();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In `readFile` `BufferedReader` wraps `FileReader` and `FileReader` is created *inside* that method so you have no opportunity to mock `FileReader` which means that you have no way to mock the inputs into your `BufferedReader` instance.

This approach makes testing difficult.

I'd suggest changing your approach. For example:

```
public ArrayList<String> readFile(BufferedReader reader) {
    // ...
}
```

Then your test could be:

```
@Test
public void readFileTest() throws Exception {
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = Mockito.mock(BufferedReader.class);
    Mockito.when(bufferedReader.readLine()).thenReturn("a", "b", "c", null);
    List<String> expected = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c");
    Assert.assertEquals("", expected, readFile(bufferedReader));
}
```

Or without Mockito at all:

```
@Test
public void readFileTest() throws Exception {
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new StringReader("a\nb\nc"));
    List<String> expected = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c");
    Assert.assertEquals("", expected, readFile(bufferedReader));
}
```

Another approach would be to create an actual file and read it i.e. no need for mocking anything. You could use JUnit's [Temporary Folder Rule](http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/rules/TemporaryFolder.html) to help clean up after the test.

On a separate note: the `readFile()` isn't closing the `BufferedReader` and `FileReader` safely.

Comment: Thank you, I looked your answer this afternoon. I think in my case it just move the issue from one step (i may have a structure issue). But I have now a method in another class that use readFile(), the call is this :  
`lines = fileUtil.readFile(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(STORAGE_DIRECTORY,FilenameUtils.getName(context)))));`
Around this call of method, i make some process with the List returned. But when i want to test this method, the File in constructor is not found even if i mock the method. 

What's the best way ? Create a temporary file ?

Comment: I'm not sure if I am following your last post correctly but it's certainly true that the easiest ways to avoid playing around with Mockito here are (a) pass a pre populated `BufferedReader` into `fileUtil.readFile()` (like I showed in the second example test in my answer) or (b) create a real file, use it and then discard it in your test case (and my link to JUnit's Temporary FOlder RUle shows you a neat way to look after the create-then-discard semantics).